# PS - JPEG 2000 saveOption

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

Is there a JPEG2000 save option in Photoshop java scripting? I can't seem to find it in the java script documentation. I'm hoping that java script will help with the saved file size issue I'm having.

I'm trying to run the Automate-Batch with some actions before saving it into a JP2 file. I notice that the file size are bigger when I run the Automate-Batch with 'save & close' and 'override action "save as" commands' compare to doing the 'save as' manually.

I have a 'save as' action that sets the quality to 50% included in the end of the action.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how your code currently looks like? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @shaedrich - That's the problem - there's no documentation for it! `jpg2kSaveOptions = new JPEG2000SaveOptions();// ????`

Comment: Is it possible to have a java script to tell Photoshop to click the 'ok' button while opening the JPEG2000 save as dialog window to save the file? I will then include the script action after the save as action ( opening up the save dialog window ).

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question! There should be documentation for it. I too cannot find any. Which messes up creating any save options:

```
  // var jpgFile = new File(filePath);
  // jpg2kSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions() ?????;
```

However, with the ScriptListener you can create a save function:

```
jpeg_2000("C:\\myfile.jpf", 100);

function jpeg_2000(filePath, jpgQuality)
{

  var idsave = charIDToTypeID( "save" );
  var desc1663 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idAs = charIDToTypeID( "As  " );
  var desc1664 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idJPLS = charIDToTypeID( "JPLS" );
  desc1664.putBoolean( idJPLS, true );
  var idJPQL = charIDToTypeID( "JPQL" );
  desc1664.putInteger( idJPQL, jpgQuality ); // jpeg200 quality
  var idJPFM = charIDToTypeID( "JPFM" );
  desc1664.putBoolean( idJPFM, true );
  var idJPMD = charIDToTypeID( "JPMD" );
  desc1664.putBoolean( idJPMD, true );
  var idJPTP = charIDToTypeID( "JPTP" );
  desc1664.putBoolean( idJPTP, false );
  var idJPJC = charIDToTypeID( "JPJC" );
  desc1664.putBoolean( idJPJC, true );
  var idJPEH = charIDToTypeID( "JPEH" );
  desc1664.putInteger( idJPEH, 50 );
  var idJPPO = charIDToTypeID( "JPPO" );
  desc1664.putInteger( idJPPO, 0 );
  var idJPCS = charIDToTypeID( "JPCS" );
  desc1664.putBoolean( idJPCS, false );
  var idJPWF = charIDToTypeID( "JPWF" );
  desc1664.putInteger( idJPWF, 1 );
  var idJPTS = charIDToTypeID( "JPTS" );
  desc1664.putInteger( idJPTS, 3 );
  var idJPJX = charIDToTypeID( "JPJX" );
  desc1664.putBoolean( idJPJX, false );
  var idJPXM = charIDToTypeID( "JPXM" );
  desc1664.putBoolean( idJPXM, true );
  var idJPEX = charIDToTypeID( "JPEX" );
  desc1664.putBoolean( idJPEX, true );
  var idJPIP = charIDToTypeID( "JPIP" );
  desc1664.putBoolean( idJPIP, false );
  var idJPRP = charIDToTypeID( "JPRP" );
  desc1664.putBoolean( idJPRP, false );
  var idJPEV = charIDToTypeID( "JPEV" );
  desc1664.putInteger( idJPEV, 16 );
  var idJPIS = charIDToTypeID( "JPIS" );
  desc1664.putInteger( idJPIS, 0 );
  var idJPRS = charIDToTypeID( "JPRS" );
  desc1664.putInteger( idJPRS, 2 );
  var idJPEGtwozerozerozero = stringIDToTypeID( " JPEG 2000" );
  desc1663.putObject( idAs, idJPEGtwozerozerozero, desc1664 );
  var idIn = charIDToTypeID( "In  " );
  desc1663.putPath( idIn, new File( filePath ) );
  var idDocI = charIDToTypeID( "DocI" );
  desc1663.putInteger( idDocI, 997 );
  var idsaveStage = stringIDToTypeID( "saveStage" );
  var idsaveStageType = stringIDToTypeID( "saveStageType" );
  var idsaveSucceeded = stringIDToTypeID( "saveSucceeded" );
  desc1663.putEnumerated( idsaveStage, idsaveStageType, idsaveSucceeded );
  executeAction( idsave, desc1663, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

I've not looked over all the options but you can repeat what I've done and adjust it to your needs.

Comment: I tried that. What I dont understand is why there is a file size different comparing to saving with the script to manually doing the 'save as'.